# Which config files for a LAMP Drupal site should be held in source control?

Tags: drupal, version-control, lamp

My team are generally .Net developers but we are currently building a Drupal site, so I am less familiar with standard practice for the LAMP stack.

We finally have the servers configured how we need them to be, so I want to make sure the relevant config files are put into our source control system, so we can track any changes.

I have taken copies of the files below, but I'm not sure if there are any other files that I've missed:

- `httpd.conf`
- `php.ini`
- `.htpasswd`

We already have a strategy for storing the Drupal modules and so on and we don't have any `.htaccess` files, but are there any other config files that I should be storing for a LAMP-based Drupal site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your configuration, you may have used virtual host files and might need to reference `/etc/apache2/sites-available/vhost` and/or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as well as `/etc/apache2/conf.d/servername.conf`.

You may also have certain settings in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, but again it depends on how you set up your lamp-stack.

As well as `.htaccess`, you should reference the drupal file `settings.php`, if only for security.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `settings.php`, which I've now added. I don't have any of the other files you mention on my RedHat box here, but we do have a bunch of `.ini` files in `/etc/php.d/` that I've also added, thanks.

Comment: Update: I've also ended up adding `/etc/mime.types`, as it seemed prudent to make sure these are kept in sync, as much as anything else.

Comment: I've also added all the files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` as well, having forgotten that there were a bunch of things there that could be relevant (in particular my `ssl.conf`).

Comment: Yep, depends on each LAMP servers config, as there are many set-ups. If you use modules such as mod-security, you'll need to add those config files also.